# Request return NULL in dropdown select

Tags: laravel

I want to save `warehouse_id` to my database, but when I `dd($request->all())` in my controller after submitting the form, `warehouse_id` returns `NULL`

This is my controller code:

```php
public function receivedAll(Request $request, ItemPR $item_code)
{

    $item_code      = $request->item_code;
    $pr_qty         = $request->pr_qty;
    $warehouse_id   = $request->warehouse_id;
    dd($request->all());

}
```

This is my blade template file:

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" method="POST" action="{{route('inventory.receivedAll') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="input-warehouse_id">Warehouse List</label>

        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="custom-select" name="warehouse_id" id="input-warehouse_id">
                <option value="">Select Warehouse</option>
                @foreach($warehouse as $data)
                    <option value="{{$data->id}}">{{$data->name}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

You can see it returns null...

[image]

`warehouse_id` has already been made **fillable** in my model, but keeps returning `NULL`, please help me fix this code.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked that the values of the select options are actually being populated correctly in the HTML?

Comment: Where is the form submit button? Are you using AJAX?

Comment: whats do you mean ? i dont understand your answer, can you give me example ?

Comment: no i, dont using AJAX

Comment: Check if your `<select>` contain the `<option>` you are adding with `@foreach` in your DOM tree by using browser developer tools.

Comment: Replace `<option value="{{$data->id}}">` with `<option value="TEST">` and then submit the form. If your `warehouse_id` is `TEST`, then there is a problem with your `$warehouse` variable in that it doesn't contain an `id` property.

Comment: wowww !! its SOLVED,, in y query before $warehouse = Warehouse::select('name')->get(); i changed to $warehouse = Warehouse::get(); its works

Comment: @Bian glad you got it solved. Any property you want to access must be included in the select, so you could have also changed it to `$warehouse = Warehouse::select('id', 'name')->get(); `

Comment: @DarrenTaylor Please can you add this as an answer? :)

Comment: @RossWilson added, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If your controller is receiving `NULL`, it's because it's being passed `NULL` from the front end.

As a test, you can replace `<option value="{{$data->id}}">` with `<option value="TEST">` and then submit the form. If your `warehouse_id` is now `TEST`, then there is a problem with your `$warehouse` variable in that it doesn't contain an id property.

This is because your query is:

```php
$warehouse = Warehouse::select('name')->get();
```

As you are only selecting `name`, there is no `id` property to access on your Eloquent model in your template. You must include any property you want to access in the `select` method, e.g.;

```php
$warehouse = Warehouse::select('id', 'name')->get();
```